# Rails Installer: Is it possible to upgrade ruby version without installing new version of rails installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to upgrade my ruby version that came with my rails installer on my windows machine but i failed to figure it out. Do i need to re-download the whole railsinstaller package and move my project to this new package or could anyone have an easier way of doing this upgrade through the command prompt.

Comment: Railsinstaller doesn't yet come with ruby2.0. [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) may be the only option.

Comment: I also have this same exact question, anyone? @capdiz can you let me know what have you done?

Comment: @postscripter use pik to switch through different  versions of ruby